# How to get annotations of JUnit test suite class?

Tags: java, junit, reflection, java-annotations

I have such an example of test suite class to run many test classes at once in JUnit 4.13.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    FirstTest.class,
    SecondTest.class
})
@TestSuiteAnnotation
public class TestSuite {
}
```

These are my test classes.

```
@FirstAnnotation
public class FirstTest extends ExtTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
  }

}

@SecondAnnotation
public class SecondTest extends ExtTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
  }

}


public class ExtTest {

  @Before
  public void beforeMethod() {
    System.out.println("Annotations from " + this.getClass());
    Arrays.asList(this.getClass().getAnnotations()).forEach(System.out::println);
  }

}
```

When I run test from *TestSuite.class*, the console output is:

```
Annotations from class FirstTest
@FirstAnnotation()

Annotations from class SecondTest
@SecondAnnotation()
```

Currently, `this.getClass().getAnnotations()` returns annotations from test classes (i.e. *FirstTest.class*, *SecondTest.class*). I want to obtain annotation `@TestSuiteAnnotation`, when I run tests from *TestSuite.class*.

The expected output should be:

```
Annotations from class FirstTest
@FirstAnnotation()
@TestSuiteAnnotation()

Annotations from class SecondTest
@SecondAnnotation()
@TestSuiteAnnotation()
```

**Can I somehow obtain annotation `@TestSuiteAnnotation`, when I run tests from *TestSuite.class*?**

Comment: Replace this.getClass() with TestSuiteClass.class

Comment: @Just another Java programmer I don't have access from tests in FirstClassTest.class to TestSuiteClass.class.

Comment: You are in `FirstClassTest` and you want to read annotations of `TestSuiteClass`, is it right?

Comment: @Renato Yes. More specifically, I want to use it in the class that `FirstClassTest` and `SecondClassTest` extends.

Comment: Just feel strange `FirstClassTest.class` can't access `TestSuiteClass.class`, can you elaborate more in the post?

Comment: @samabcde I edited my question to make it more specific. Also added example code to [repository](https://github.com/kosteklvp/annotationsTest) on GitHub.

Comment: Have you try putting following lines in `SecondTest` `test` method?
    `System.out.println("Annotations from " + TestSuite.class);`
    `Arrays.asList(TestSuite.class.getAnnotations()).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @samabcde I want to use it in many test suite classes. So putting this directly into the code won't solve my problem. E.g. if I'll add `SecondTestSuite.class` and run test from it will always return annotations from `TestSuite.class`.

Comment: How are the tests started? Can you use the class `JUnitCore` to start them? That would allow you to add a [run listener](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html), which provides a `testSuiteStarted` method.

Comment: @nrainer I tried this, but I think it won't work this way I want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

#### JUnit 4 run listener

On JUnit 4, you can register a `RunListener`, like *@nrainer* said. If you build with Maven, it is easy to register a run listener like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>org.acme.TestSuite</include>
    </includes>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>listener</name>
        <value>org.acme.SuiteRunListener</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The run listener can override the events `testSuiteStarted` and `testSuiteFinished` and either directly log the annotations you are interested in or assign them to a static thread-local variable like `private static ThreadLocal<List<Annotation>> currentSuiteAnnotations` in `testSuiteStarted`, then unassign it again in `testSuiteFinished`.

This works nicely from Maven, I tested it. Unfortunately, there is no direct support for running tests with run listeners from IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse. So if you want to avoid running the tests manually from a class with a main method as shown [here](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html), because it would take away all the nice IDE test reporting with drill-down from suite to test class to test method, this is not an option.

#### JUnit 5 test execution listener

Similar to JUnit 4's run listener, you can register a [`TestExecutionListener`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom) for your JUnit 5 tests. The advantage in JUnit 5 is that you can register it globally via Java's s [ServiceLoader](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom) mechanism, i.e. it will be picked up when bootstrapping JUnit and should also work in IDEs. I did something similar with another type of extension, and it worked nicely in IntelliJ IDEA and of course also in Maven.

#### JUnit 4 with custom suite runner

Coming back to JUnit 4, we can extend the first approach with the run listener by declaring a special type of suite. You simply use that suite instead of `org.junit.runners.Suite` and can enjoy the working run listener in both Maven and the IDE. It works like that, see also my [MCVE on GitHub](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_Java_JUnit4DetermineSuiteFromTestClass_69572718) for your convenience:

```java
package org.acme;

import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SuiteRunListener extends RunListener {
  private static ThreadLocal<String> currentSuiteName = new ThreadLocal<String>();
  private static ThreadLocal<List<Annotation>> currentSuiteAnnotations = new ThreadLocal<>();

  @Override
  public void testSuiteStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
    super.testSuiteStarted(description);
    final RunWith runWith = description.getAnnotation(RunWith.class);
    if (runWith != null && runWith.value().equals(SuiteWithListener.class)) {
      currentSuiteName.set(description.getDisplayName());
      currentSuiteAnnotations.set(
        description.getAnnotations().stream()
          .filter(annotation -> {
            final Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType = annotation.annotationType();
            return !(annotationType.equals(RunWith.class) || annotationType.equals(SuiteClasses.class));
          })
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
      );
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void testSuiteFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
    super.testSuiteFinished(description);
    final RunWith runWith = description.getAnnotation(RunWith.class);
    if (runWith != null && runWith.value().equals(SuiteWithListener.class)) {
      currentSuiteName.set(null);
      currentSuiteAnnotations.set(null);
    }
  }

  public static String getCurrentSuiteName() {
    return currentSuiteName.get();
  }

  public static List<Annotation> getCurrentSuiteAnnotations() {
    return currentSuiteAnnotations.get();
  }
}
```

```java
package org.acme;

import org.junit.runner.Runner;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder;

import java.util.List;

public class SuiteWithListener extends Suite {
  public SuiteWithListener(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass, builder);
  }

  public SuiteWithListener(RunnerBuilder builder, Class<?>[] classes) throws InitializationError {
    super(builder, classes);
  }

  protected SuiteWithListener(Class<?> klass, Class<?>[] suiteClasses) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass, suiteClasses);
  }

  protected SuiteWithListener(RunnerBuilder builder, Class<?> klass, Class<?>[] suiteClasses) throws InitializationError {
    super(builder, klass, suiteClasses);
  }

  protected SuiteWithListener(Class<?> klass, List<Runner> runners) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass, runners);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
    notifier.addListener(new SuiteRunListener());  // !!!
    super.run(notifier);
  }
}
```

```java
package org.acme;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(SuiteWithListener.class)  // !!!
@SuiteClasses({
  FirstTest.class,
  SecondTest.class
})
@TestSuiteAnnotation
public class TestSuite {}
```

```java
package org.acme;

import org.junit.Before;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ExtTest {
  @Before
  public void beforeMethod() {
    String currentSuiteName = SuiteRunListener.getCurrentSuiteName();
    if (currentSuiteName != null) {
      System.out.println("Annotations from suite " + currentSuiteName);
      SuiteRunListener.getCurrentSuiteAnnotations().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    System.out.println("Annotations from class " + this.getClass());
    Arrays.asList(this.getClass().getAnnotations()).forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Now when running your suite, you should see output like this:

```
Annotations from suite org.acme.TestSuite
@org.acme.TestSuiteAnnotation()
Annotations from class class org.acme.FirstTest
@org.acme.FirstAnnotation()

Annotations from suite org.acme.TestSuite
@org.acme.TestSuiteAnnotation()
Annotations from class class org.acme.SecondTest
@org.acme.SecondAnnotation()
```

**Please note:** I was assuming that you really need access to the current suite from each single test method, not just at the test class or suite level. If you do not need that and it is enough to let the run listener do something when a suite is started and/or finished, of course you do not need the getter methods for current suite name and suite annotations. I just extended your own example.

Comment: Third option is the solution I was looking for. I had a similar idea, but after extending `Suite` class, I didn't know what to do next. I didn't think about adding custom `RunListener`.
Works like a charm. Thanks.